# Fetch 2 tables in php not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch

I got to obtain all values of a foreign key. It goes like this:
I got two tables:Subjects and Careers -> "Subjects" includes (id, careers_id (is the foreign key to the column "id" of the table Careers) name, description, hours) "Careers" includes (id,name,description)

First of all, i got to show a table which contains this:
[Final_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vUIC.png)
But, in that table i have writen the subjects (calculus,physics,biology) by myself and that's wrong. I should fetch that information from both tables (subjects and careers). And i also need to add new subjects - i mean when i click on "Add new subject" it goes to another page and from the option "Subjects" there must be a slider/select with all the careers from the table.
So:
1)I need to fetch the information from the foreign key
2)I need to select careers when i want to  add a new subject

Here is my code (this one create a table, but it's not fetch the information from the table Careers):

```
</head>
<body>
<a href="estudiante.php">ADD NEW SUBJECT</a><br /><br />
    <h2 align="center">TABLE:SUBJECTS</h2>
        <table align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700">
            <thead>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Career</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Hours</th>
                <th>Action</th>

            </thead>

            <?php
            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subjects");
            $i=1;
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>".$i."</td>
                            <td>".$row['careers_id']."</td>
                            <td>".$row['name']."</td>
                            <td>".$row['description']."</td>
                            <td>".$row['hours']."</td>
                            <td align='center'>
                                <a href='editar.php?editar=1&iden=".$row['id']."'>UPDATE</a> |
                                <a href='borrar.php?borrar=1&iden=".$row['id']."'>DELETE</a>
                            </td>
                    </tr>";
                    $i++;

                }
            ?>

        </table>    

</body>
```

And this code is to add a new subject:

```
<?php include('connect.php'); 
$error="";

if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
{
    $carreras_id=$_POST['txtcarreras_id'];
    $nombre=$_POST['txtnombre'];
    $descripcion=$_POST['txtdescripcion'];
    $carga_horaria=$_POST['txtcarga_horaria'];


    if($_POST['txtid']=="0")
    {

        $a_sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO subjects VALUES('','$carreras_id','$nombre','$descripcion','$carga_horaria')");
        if($a_sql)
        {

            header("location:index.php");

        }


    }else{

        echo "Actualizar";
    }

}
```

?>

```
        <h2 align="center">ADD NEW SUBJECT</h2>
        <form method="Post">
            <table align="center">
                <tr>    
                    <td>Career:</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='txtcarreras_id'/><input type="hidden" name="txtid" value="0" /></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='txtnombre'/></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td>Description:</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='txtdescripcion'/></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td>Hours:</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='txtcarga_horaria'/></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type='submit' value=save name='btnsave'/></td>

                </tr>
            </table>


        </form>
```

Please, i really dont know whatto do :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
 $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subjects");
```

to this

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subjects s INNER JOIN careers c ON s.careers_id = c.id");
```

You need to add a `join` in query

New subject

```
<form method="Post">
            <table align="center">
                <tr>    
                    <td>Career:</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='txtcarreras_id'/><input type="hidden" name="txtid" value="0" /></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='txtnombre'/></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td>Description:</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='txtdescripcion'/></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td>Hours:</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='txtcarga_horaria'/></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type='submit' value=save name='btnsave'/></td>

             </tr>
           <tr>
               <select name="new_sub">
                   <?php foreach(){?> <option value="<?php echo $row['careers_id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option> <?php } ?>
               </select>
           </tr>
       </table>


    </form>
```

Comment: Hey dude,thank you for reply :). But now the table doesnt show anything:(

Comment: Yeah, it is working!. But how can i get a "select" with all the careers when iwant to add a new subject?

Answer (score 0):

To obtain values from 2 tables you might want to use [SQL JOIN clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Change this:

```
SELECT * FROM subjects
```

to following:

```
SELECT subjects.name,subjects.hours,careers.description...(choose the columns you want) FROM subjects INNER JOIN careers ON subjects.careers_id=careers.id;
```

If you want to make for example a dropdown -menu with all the careers:

```
all_careers = mysql_query(get all the careers and corresponding career_id from the table);
```

Then in your form you could have some php between 'dropdown'-html tags,like this:

```
    <select>

    <?php
    here go through all_careers(You can use foreach -construct) and on each cycle print out new career option:
    echo "<option value=\"".[career_id here]."\">".[career name here]."</option>";
    ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply!
But what should i do to get an slider/select with all the careers when i want to add a new subject?

Comment: Dude, can you please check this: :/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879641/fetch-tables-not-working-properly